# understanding npm script (webpack-dev-server)

Tags: webpack-dev-server

I have a question about npm run.

('npm run dev' is from https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews/blob/gh-pages/package.json)

```
{
  "name": "vue-hackernews",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "HN clone with Vue.js using HN API",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --no-info",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
     ....
  },
```

why does 'npm run dev' go well,

but does other commands like 'npm run webpack-dev-server'

or just 'webpack-dev-server' throw errors?

what does 'npm run' do? not just executing the value of the property of "scripts"?

( which I was thinking 'command exactly same thing')

thank you!

Comment: if i installed webpack-dev-server globally, can I use 'webpack-dev-server' at anywhere? and that means, npm run always search the exact same name of the module's folder?

Comment: did my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42351919/2545680) help?

Answer (score 2):

> just 'webpack-dev-server' throw errors?

because in order for it to work, `webpack-dev-server` has to be added to the `PATH` environment variable. If you use `npm run script-name`, [then](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script):

> In addition to the shell's pre-existing PATH, npm run adds
>   node_modules/.bin to the PATH provided to scripts.

check `node_modules/.bin` folder, you'll see `webpack-dev-server` there, and this executable runs the `js` package like this:

```
node  "$basedir/../webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js" "$@"
```

Another alternative is this if you're on Unix based env:

```
$(npm bin)/webpack-dev-server'
```